# Did Petyr Baelish intend for Lysa to see him kiss Sansa Stark?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In [Season 4, Episode 7](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3060876/?ref_=ttep_ep7) of *Game of Thrones*, Petyr Baelish kisses Sansa Stark after she creates her snow castle of Winterfell.
[image: kiss]

His wife, Lysa goes into a jealous rage and threatens Sansa's life.  Lord Baelish then proceeds to throw Lysa out of the moon door to her death.

**Did Lord Baelish kiss Sansa to ensure that Lysa would see the kiss and go into a rage?  Was this a plan by Lord Baelish to set up Lysa's death?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the surface it seems unlikely that Petyr could have coordinated the events that happened...

1. It being snowing.
2. Sansa being in the courtyard building the castle.
3. Sweet Robin showing up, destroying the castle, causing Sansa grief.
4. Lysa being there at the right moment.
5. Lysa flying into a rage and trying push Sana through the Moon Door.

*However*, this is Petyr "Chaos is a ladder" Baelish, and I have no doubt that it was in his greater plan to remove Lysa from the picture as this would cement his position as Lord of the Eyrie, so let us examine the process...

1. Petyr wakes up to find it snowing, not an unusual event for that time of year in the Eyrie.
2. Petyr sees Sansa building the snow castle and (unknown to us) notices Lysa keeping an eye on her.
3. Petyr sends Robin to play with Sansa, knowing that something will happen.
4. Knowing that Lysa is watching and of her jealousy of Catelyn and how much Sansa resembles her, he goes for the kiss.
5. Upon Lysa's descent into rage, Petyr capitalizes on the opportunity.

It does all seems very unlikely, but remember this is the same man who was the catalyst for the downfall of at least three major houses (Arryn, Stark, Baratheon). Having known Lysa since childhood and considering the conspiracy they planned, it is likely Petyr had a good idea of how Lysa would react.

**So in the end, an opportunity presented itself, and true to his character Littlefinger seized it for his own ends!**

We have no explicit confirmation of this (other than knowing he eventually wanted Lysa dead) even when Littlefinger is opening up about what his long game is. Even the books, which if nothing else can provide clues to motives in the show, offer nothing as Petyr has no POV chapters.

Comment: Excuse me sir, wh're art thy sources?

Comment: @Edlothiad more of character analysis and based on other plots we have seen carried out.

Comment: [sources](https://www.amazon.com/Game-Thrones-Complete-Fourth-Blu-ray/dp/B00KHWSD1O)

Comment: @KutuluMike I was expecting your link to be [sources](https://cdn.meme.am/instances/48622742.jpg).

Comment: Here's them [sauces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sauces) you asked for.